# URLRequest header permanent

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift3

I have webView in which I load some url. I need to set custom header for that URLRequest. For the first request it works as expected, header is received on server side and content is displayed accordingly. However if I open another link from displayed page, headers are lost and request is sent without header.

My lucky guess is that, header is added only for the first time and I have to add it every time when request to load url is sent. However I couldn't find method where can I do so.

Currently I'm setting header in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    myWebView.delegate = self

    let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com");
    var requestobj = URLRequest(url: url!);
    requestobj.addValue("my_request_id", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With");

    myWebView.loadRequest(requestobj);

}
```

Am I missing something or should I add header in different place for every request?

Comment: Implement this delegate function `func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, 
  shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, 
       navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool` for all new request within webview this method gets called you can get the url of the request and you can make a new request with added header if the URL is not the parent url.

Comment: That could work. However request here is _immutable_, so I have to copy it to new _var_, then _addValue_, but how can I set it back to webView?

Comment: You need to create New request, if your WebView supports navigation then you need to maintain array of urls, and instead of navigating you need to create new request from array everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to iphonic, to pointing at shouldStartLoadWith. I could use that to understand is request new or old one and solve my problem by doing so:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView,
                      shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest,
                      navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool{


   if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked) 
   {

        var req = request; 

        req.addValue("my_request_id", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With"); 


        self.myWebView.loadRequest(req); 
            return false; 

    }
    else {
        return true; 
    }



}
```

So here I check, if navigation type is clickedLink, then I don't load current request, instead I copy it, reapply custom header and load it into myWebView. 
If navigationType isn't linkClicked, I proceed request without changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should add custom headers each time when you create request.